# Ember urlForFindAll and BuildURL for DS.RESTAdapter prepend modelName value when overridden

Tags: ember.js, adapter

This urlForFindAll function returns 'api/live/liveSites'.
The GET request is made to 'site/api/live/liveSites'
Where site is the modelName.
I tried similar code with buildURL instead and had the same issue.

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api',
  urlForFindAll: function (modelName, snapshot) {
    var url = this.namespace;
    if (snapshot.adapterOptions.siteType === 'live') {
      url += '/live/liveSites';
    } else {
       url +='/site/standard/standardSites';
    }
    return url;
  }
});
```

This is the call in question.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model () {
    return this.store.findAll('site', {
      adapterOptions: {
        siteType: 'live'
      }
    }).then(function (sites) {
      return sites.toArray();
    });
  }
})
```

Why is the url I return from urlForFindAll or BuildURL not the one to which the request is made?

Edit: I'm on node 4 and ember-cli 2.11

Edit 2: So I've been playing around with different API calls and it actually seems like it's prepending the route URL from which the request is made...
EG: If my current route is site/edit/site_id, the request would be made to site/edit/site_id/api/live/liveSites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED: I had to prepend a '/' to what I return from urlForFindAll. Unfortunately the Ember documentation doesn't really reflect this.

so:
    return '/' + url;

fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks perfect. Just ensure that you created specific `Adapter` for `site` model, which may or may not extend application adapter depends on your need.
example `adapters/site.js`

Comment: I made a second edit as new information came in from playing around with the code. Any thoughts? It seems like it's actually prepending the route path, not the model name.